# vueJs how to create angular like directive?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to have an angular like directive in vue,

I will get some templates containing element and specific attribute like this one :

```
<div container-id=""></div>
```

When in the DOM I have an element with an attribute conatiner-id, I want to change the background color of my div for instance.

The fact is I don't want to have in my dom, attribute like : v-container-id 
I can't actually modify the template

Comment: You can change the background color of a div based on an attribute using CSS: `[container-id] { background-color: red; }`

Comment: @RoyJ Sure I can but it's a very simple example for me to avoid explaining too much about what I want to do in my directive ...

Comment: Simple isolated DOM changes can be done with [Vue directives](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html). Things that require interaction with the DOM or data outside the directive element should be done with [custom components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html).